# How to get all variables passed to a function in autoit?

Tags: autoit

Just like `func_get_args` in [PHP](https://www.php.net/func_get_args), I swear I have seen it somewhere in the documentation...

Comment: I don't think there is an exactly analogous feature in AutoIt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is `@NumParams` which returns the number of parameters used when calling a function.